# Dynamic Multithreading lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to create an structure to control dynamically locks. For example, I have 100 threads running, and each thread will "process" a "key". Sometimes two threads could be processing the same "key", and if it occurs, a dynamic lock needs to be created and used by both, to process one at a time.

I create the following structure and I would like a code review, to find possible bugs (even if it is extremely rare):

```
  // This is the class who control to create one different lock for each key.
    public class DynamicLockGenerator
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _locksByKeys = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static objectGetLock(string key)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_locksByKeys.ContainsKey(key))
                _locksByKeys.Add(key, new object());

            return _locksByKeys[key];
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveLock(string key)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            //This line is extremely important: One lock object can only be removed
            //if no thread are using it.
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locksByKeys[key]))
            {
                _locksByKeys.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}

//This is the use of the class. All threads do the same thing, but with different (or equal) keys.
object lockObj = DynamicLockGenerator.GetLock(key);

lock (lockObj)
{
    //PROCESS THE KEY
}

DynamicLockGenerator.RemoveLock(key);
```

Comment: Maybe you could just use the key as lock object!? Using `string.intern` ensures that you get always the same instance of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have the potential for a race condition if one thread releases the lock and removes it, after another thread has got the lock but not yet locked it.

```
Thread one GetLock(someKey) // Creates lock, returns dynamic key
Thread one Lock(dynamicKey)
Thread one complete processing (exits lock section)
Thread two GetLock(someKey) // returns existing key
Thread one RemoveLock // removes lock from collection (not yet being used)
Thread two Lock(dynamicKey) // Now we've locked an object no longer in collection
Thread two complete processing (exit lock block)
Thread two Remove lock // tries to remove a lock that's not in the collection
```

Comment: Thank you by the answer, you are right. But could you help-me how could I do this dynamic lock? No answers of stackoverflow and google helps-me until now.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind The easiest way to fix the problem I've highlighted is to never remove the lock objects from `_locksByKeys`.  Whether or not that's practical obviously depends on the number of unique keys you're expecting and how long running the process is that your code will sit in.

Comment: I have alread thought about this, but I have a looooooooot of keys to process, so if I do this memory leak could appear.

Comment: I had an idea, I am developing now and I will edit my question later.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind I'm fairly new to code review, but I think the preferred process is for you to leave your current question as it is and submit any subsequent versions as a new question, that way the code and reviews don't get out of sync.

Comment: Here is my new code: 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128599/dynamic-multi-threading-lock-with-while-loop-c